# Preserve caret/bookmark position in tiny while using setContent

Tags: tinymce

I am working on an open source product to allow collaborative editing in a CMS. The use case is the following:
While user A is editing some tiny node user B updates the same node. Everything is working fine updating user's A tiny editor except preserving his cursor position. I.e.

```
var bookmark = editor.selection.getBookmark();
editor.setContent(content);
editor.selection.moveToBookmark(bookmark);
```

will not work if the contents have changed *before* the caret.
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=20458 mentions that there would be an update to deal with this kind of situation, but is there something I could do now?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be a fumbling thing to achieve, but here is a onother way.
You could use a formalized bookmark. The code will look like

```
var bookmark = editor.selection.getBookmark(2, true);
editor.setContent(content);
editor.selection.moveToBookmark(bookmark);
```

Comment: Fumbling it is :) However the above does not seem to work for me. Using 2, after set content the cursor is set to the beginning of the node. Using 0 does not, but still has the problem when the contents change before the cursor. Any more suggestions?

Comment: can you give some more information of how your use case works? (how both users are enabled to work on the same editor, how and when the content gets set/updated aso...)

Comment: Thank you for your persistence! It's kind of hard to explain: There is an XMPP application that runs in the same time. Every time a node changes, a patch is created and sent to other users. Upon receipt their browser will match the patch with the node's content and apply it to the node. For the case of a tiny node that means: Use getContent, apply the patch, setContent. You can have a look (but it's complex) at https://github.com/ggozad/jarn.xmpp.collaboration/blob/master/jarn/xmpp/collaboration/browser/js/collaborate.js

Comment: There is also the possibility of rather than dealing with all this complexity, adding some visual element to indicate each user's position in the node. Then setting the cursor would be a matter of setting the bookmark at that element. Thoughts?

Comment: oh yeah, that looks somewhat complex. i had a thought like that: you could insert a special element or a regular element with a special class or something into the editor at the cursor position (there is an editor command for that) and when calling setContent on the other clients editor you place the cursor there (+ removing that node)

Comment: Thank you for your effort, that alone deserves closing this even if not resolved :)

Comment: I've got the same problem, could you tell us how exactly you solved it in the end?

Comment: This works, but why? The documentation doesn't fully define the getBookmark() params. See: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.dom.Selection.getBookmark
Can you explain the `2` and `true` params?

Comment: you can create html bookmarks using editor.selection.getBookmark() or you can create a non-html-bookmark using getBookmark(2, true). Actually i do not recall why the second paramter has to be true, but you may chack it out yourself - just log the created bookmarks to your console. Tne non-html bookmark is an array defining which child (from the body) is the cursor at plus an offset. It is sometimes necessary to use non-html bookmarks because html-bookmarks can get lost with a reset of the editor body for example.